# retrieve children information firebase android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this code which I want to read all the products from **`Firebase`**, and display their information in **`ListView`**, but I couldn't reach the products info, how can I do it?
this is my code:

```
public class Product_List extends AppCompatActivity {

    DatabaseReference mDatabase;
    ListView productsList;
    ArrayList<Product> products;
    DatabaseReference productsRef;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_product__list);
//        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        productsRef = mDatabase.child("products");
        ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    String productID = ds.getKey();
                    DatabaseReference Product = productsRef.child(productID);
                    String productName = Product.child("product_name").toString();
                    Product a = new Product(productName,"a","a","a",1,1);
                    products.add(a);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
        };
        productsRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);

        LinearLayout productList = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ProductList);
        productAdapter itemsAdapter = new productAdapter(this, products);
        productsList = (ListView) findViewById(listView);
        productsList.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);
//

    }
}
```

But my app crashes when I did this!

[image: here a screenshot of my database]

UPDATE:

when I tried to do this:

```
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

            Product product = ds.getValue(Product.class);
            products.add(product);
        }
```

I got this error :(

```
11-08 16:21:10.374 5270-5270/com.example.kamran.bluewhite E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                            Process: com.example.kamran.bluewhite, PID: 5270
                                                                            com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to convert a value of type java.lang.String to int
                                                                                at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzaz(Unknown Source)
                                                                                at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzc(Unknown Source)
                                                                                at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzb(Unknown Source)
                                                                                at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                                at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzb(Unknown Source)
                                                                                at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi$zza.zze(Unknown Source)
                                                                                at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi$zza.zzaG(Unknown Source)
                                                                                at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zze(Unknown Source)
                                                                                at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzb(Unknown Source)
                                                                                at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                                at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(Unknown Source)
                                                                                at com.example.kamran.bluewhite.Product_List$1.onDataChange(Product_List.java:57)
                                                                                at com.google.firebase.database.Query$1.onDataChange(Unknown Source)
                                                                                at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbmz.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                                at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbnz.zzYj(Unknown Source)
                                                                                at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzboc$1.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
11-08 16:21:10.376 1654-2210/system_process W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.example.kamran.bluewhite/.Product_List
```

Line 57 at product_List is:

```
 Product product = ds.getValue(Product.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the data inside the products, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference productsRef = rootRef.child("products");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            int ammount = ds.child("ammount").getValue(Integer.class);
            String brand = ds.child("brand").getValue(String.class);
            String category = ds.child("category").getValue(String.class);
            String description = ds.child("description").getValue(String.class);
            int price = ds.child("price").getValue(Integer.class);
            String product_name = ds.child("product_name").getValue(String.class);
            Log.d("TAG", ammount + " / " + 
                     brand + " / " + 
                     category + " / " + 
                     description + " / " + 
                     price + " / " + 
                     product_name);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
productsRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

Your output will be:

```
 1 / fdgh / ghgh / rawan / 11 / r
//and so on for other products
```

Comment: This code definitelly works but you don't take advantage the JAVA way which is to create a model Class for the data that you want to retrieve.

Comment: @NickZisis In this case the OP did not mentioned the way in which he is adding data to the dababase. So assuming that the data was added witout a model class, this code will still work.

Comment: Yeah I agree with you @AlexMamo, and as I mentioned  in my above comment this code definitelly works. I was just saying that is a good practice to use the Model Class.

Comment: I have model class of product, I tried the @Nick Zisis solution but my app still crashing, I have updated my question with the error

Comment: If you see the error, it indicates that there is a problem with data types of firebase, so if that is the case you solution will not work.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String productID = ds.getKey();
                DatabaseReference Product = productsRef.child(productID);
                String productName = Product.child("product_name").toString();
                Product a = new Product(productName,"a","a","a",1,1);
                products.add(a);
            }
```

I wouldn't implement that way. First I would create a Java class that will be the model for the product.

```
class Product{
private double amount;
private String brand;
private String category;
private String description;
private double price;
private String product_name;

public Product(){
}
//Setters and getters for each field
}
```

After you create the Product class this is the code to retrieve the data.

```
        ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Product product = ds.getValue(Product.class);
                //Here you have successfully retrieve one Product and from here you can do 
                //anything you need.
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
    };
```

In this link https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data you can check the instructions from Firebase on how you retrieve data.

Comment: Can you post the error from you IDE to have a better overview?

Comment: Yeah I saw the error, the problem is that the Model class fields types are not  the same with the data that you have saved in Firebase so you get this error. Try to match the names and the types of the Model class with the Firebase Data and you will not have any problem. And if the error persists check all the data of products because you may have saved different types in the same field.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try `ChildEventListener`

```
ChildEventListener childEventListener = new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onChildAdded:" + dataSnapshot.getKey());

        // A new comment has been added, add it to the displayed list
        Product roduct = dataSnapshot.getValue(Product.class);

        // ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onChildChanged:" + dataSnapshot.getKey());

    }

    @Override
    public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onChildRemoved:" + dataSnapshot.getKey());
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onChildMoved:" + dataSnapshot.getKey());
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.w(TAG, "postComments:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
    }
};
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
productsRef = mDatabase.child("products");
productsRef.addChildEventListener(childEventListener);
```

Please refer https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data